# Would it be possible/beneficial to use interactive samples in questions/answers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I see quite a few interesting questions on Stack Overflow where some basic interactive demos could add to the text/code explanations.

For example, for some [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29) related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320162/processing-how-can-i-improve-the-framerate-in-my-program), and even some [ActionScript related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349375/algorithm-to-solve-the-points-of-a-evenly-distributed-even-gaps-spiral) related ones, an interactive demo could help reduce text and image usage.

I imagine for questions like this, having the option to mark code as an

> 'Active Code Sample'

and run it through [ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/) would be fun.

On ActionScript related questions, I admit this might be stretch, since a lot of people disable Flash by default and some hate it, but maybe embedding demos written on [wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/) might help questions/answers.

Just a thought.

Opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like way too much work for a way too small subset of applicable questions. It also adds a number of security and privacy issues.

I think this should be solved by linking to some external service like JSFiddle. I don't know whether such a service exists for Actionscript samles.

Comment: I imagine either sketches could be saved in a 3rd party location like http://hascanvas.com or http://sketchpad.cc/ , sandboxed to prevent any dodgy behaviours. Regarding actionscript, wouldn't wonderfl.net be somewhat equivalent ? Otherwise, I don't fully understand.

Comment: @George I don't see the point of having this somehow embedded in SO's content - it's  so easy to just link to it, isn't it?

Comment: You're right, it could just be a link. I was thinking it might be easier to keep altogether somehow, you wouldn't need to have two windows: one for the explanations, and one for the demo side by side or switch between them, it would all be an integral part of an answer...then again it might be little things people wouldn't be annoyed with, right ?

Comment: @George I think so. It would add a lot of complexity to an otherwise very simple system. Mind you, I don't think it's a bad idea in itself... But this is better done externally I think

Comment: I think I understand...the 'cost' of implementing this for everyone vs. the benefit for the situations where it would be helpful vs. sticking to the minimal/clean current implementation. Thanks for clearing things out.

Comment: @George I'm just a user, so this is just my 2 cents of course. But I'm relatively sure the team's stance is going to be very similar in this case

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like a great idea.  ProcessingJS would be a good idea.  Let's do it.